# Spree commerce infinity loop error that make difficult to debug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, puma, rbenv

i develop my web application with spree commerce framework, that used GIT for collaboration. the first thing that caused this infinity loop errors after i have pulled from develop branch that its derived in several devices so there were several devices else not derived this errors eventhough it's in the same branch, in the same project and environments. In this case although this infinity errors occured, but the web still running but it's running slow and i have difficult to debug.
i have already tried to find solution in many references but not found the solution yet.

The errors like below :

```rb
2019-04-22 19:59:10 -0500: Listen loop error: #<Errno::EBADF: Bad file descriptor>
/Users/my_account/.rbenv/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:386:in `select'
/Users/my_account/.rbenv/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:386:in `handle_servers'
/Users/my_account/.rbenv/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:360:in `block in run'
2019-04-22 19:59:10 -0500: Listen loop error: #<Errno::EBADF: Bad file descriptor>
/Users/my_account/.rbenv/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:386:in `select'
/Users/my_account/.rbenv/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:386:in `handle_servers'
/Users/my_account/.rbenv/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:360:in `block in run'
2019-04-22 19:59:10 -0500: Listen loop error: #<Errno::EBADF: Bad file descriptor>
/Users/my_account/.rbenv/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:386:in `select'
/Users/my_account/.rbenv/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:386:in `handle_servers'
/Users/my_account/.rbenv/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/puma-3.12.1/lib/puma/server.rb:360:in `block in run'
2019-04-22 19:59:10 -0500: Listen loop error: #<Errno::EBADF: Bad file descriptor>
```

the environments that i used are :
macOS mojave 10.14.4
ruby 2.6.1
rails 5.2.3
rbenv 1.1.2
spree 3.7.0

can anybody help ? thanks before

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem once on local environment and in my case the problem appeared when I ran puma in cluster mode. Single mode works fine for me.

You probably have this line in your `puma.rb` config file: `workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || <number>)`

Try to change the `<number>` value to `0` and puma will run without spinning up child processes. Hope it will help

**UPD**: solved by gem reinstallation within gemset

for RVM it's:

1. **rvm gemset empty gemset_name**
2. **bundle install**